# Read serialport and store it in a String Variable C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, serial-port, port, c#-3.0

I have to read serialport and store that response which is a sequence of six bytes in a string variable .I am trying to store the response in string variable  by concatenate the response. But only the last byte from the response is getting stored.

```
        int response = port.ReadByte();
        string responseString = "";
        responseString  += response.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(responseString);
```

Comment: The way you read from serialport seems not right. Try the method mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754694/what-is-the-correct-way-to-read-a-serial-port-using-net-framework

Comment: Please post real [MCVE] so people can help you with your problem (i.e. currently posted code only reads one byte and always set `responseString` to empty for that single byte) . Otherwise link provided by @HaBom should be enough - maybe question should be closed as duplicate of it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754694/what-is-the-correct-way-to-read-a-serial-port-using-net-framework.

Comment: Is that code in the DataReceived() event?  If so, move the `string responseString = "";` line out the the class/form level so that it doesn't get reset each time.

Answer (score 0):

```
Port.ReadByte()
```

Synchronously reads one byte from the SerialPort input buffer.

So you probably want to use:

```
Port.ReadExisting()
```

Reads all immediately available bytes, based on the encoding, in both the stream and the input buffer of the SerialPort object.