# How to implement OCR reader using C# for ChatsWorth ACP 100 reader

Tags: c#, image-processing, ocr

I want to read the scorecard using chats worth [ACP 100](http://www.kendata.com/cardomr.html) readers. I tried to implement an application with C# to access the reader through the serial port.  But still couldn't find the proper method to do this. Could you please guide me to implement this?

tutorial or source sample will be highly appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Read the port like in: 
[What is the correct way to read a serial port using .NET framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754694/what-is-the-correct-way-to-read-a-serial-port-using-net-framework)

throw in the XonXoff handshake since the reader looks like it uses that.

```
port.Handshake = Handshake.XOnXOff;
```

see what kind of data it spits out, then see if you can decode it.