# How to detect a serial bit byte error in SerialPort class C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, serial-port, buffer

I am using System.IO.Ports.SerialPort to read data from serial communication. The problem is that I want to determine which byte is bad when I read the byte array buffer and write a file. If I know which byte is bad, then I can recreate the correct file since I know the hash of the file. But It looks like System.IO.Ports.SerialPort only gives a way to "overwrite" an erroneous byte with the SerialPort.ParityReplace property. If I'm reading a million byte array, then I don't want to set a bit pattern as a replacement value and then search for this bit pattern in the massive array since I may have lots of matches. Is there a way for me to determine which byte failed a parity check when I read the byte buffer? If not, what would be a better way for me to get parity style error detection while sending a file over serial?

The code below is the way I'm currently looking at the serial data, but I'm open to other methods if its faster or gives more reliability.

```
//... earlier code:
_serialPort.ReadBufferSize = 100000000;
//... more irrelevant code

Thread.Sleep(150000); // wait for 150 seconds for the data to come in.
byte[] HundredKBBuffer = new byte[_serialPort.ReadBufferSize]; // the byte array I'll read from
//read data then discard buffer to get new data from the transmitting machine
_serialPort.Read(HundredKBBuffer, 0, HundredKBBuffer.Length);
_serialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
Console.WriteLine("data received");
//code that reads the byte array, looks for header and trailer and writes file
findHeadAndWriteDataToFile(HundredKBBuffer);
```

Comment: Try these old protocols? [ZModem 4 dotNET](https://sourceforge.net/projects/zmodem4dotnet/), [ymodemdotnet](https://code.google.com/archive/p/ymodemdotnet/)

Comment: *"The problem is that I want to determine which byte is bad"* -- Seems like you're making an (unreasonable) assumption that there could only be a single bit or byte error in the message block. How would you account for multiple bit or byte errors? What about completely missing bytes?  FYI: it's complicated enough to reliably confirm the integrity of the received data.  To pinpoint the data in error essentially requires error correction code, aka ECC.

Comment: @sawdust I'm just keeping my question simple. I already have hashes and checksums to check for integrity from non recoverable data loss, not trying to be able to recover from that sort of problem. The only thing I'm trying to find in this problem is a 1 bit flip within a byte (detect, not fix). I can then loop through all the bytes and apply this same method. Looking for something similar to parity without massively increasing the size of the data. Hoping that .NET serial class had a built in way to pinpoint bad bytes as they come through the port

Comment: *"detect, not fix"* -- If you could detect which bit is wrong, then you automatically have correction capability.  The data is binary, so the correct value is obvious!  So you would need ECC rather than a CRC.  Also a  data bit is 4 times likelier to be in error than a framing bit (for 8N1), but that's still a 20% probability that the framing goes bad rather than just a data bit (and you lose bytes not just flipped bits).

Comment: @sawdust Obviously, detect means detect "a" bit flip within a byte (like parity), not determining which bit was flipped. Otherwise this is called error correction. I'm only looking to narrow the byte down, not the bit

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried reading the data in asynchronously as a stream instead of waiting to get the whole block at once? This sounds like it would allow you more opportunities to error check.

[What is the correct way to read a serial port using .NET framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754694/what-is-the-correct-way-to-read-a-serial-port-using-net-framework)

Comment: Good article, but I'm looking to embed error detection in my data

Answer (score -1):

First idea is to you parity check after each byte, but you could loose speed communication (1 byte of data, 1 byte of parity check).

You can laso use CRC Code which is like an extension of the parity check. For example, you send 8 bytes and the ninth byte is the CRC. This allow you to control datas for a size-specified packet. The CRC function looks like this (it is the CRC-8 function, but you can use an other one):

```
private byte CRC8(byte[] Array, int length)
    {
        byte CRC = 0x00;
        int length_buffer = length;
        int length_refreshed = length;
        CRC = Array[0];
        length_refreshed--; ;
        for (; length_refreshed > 0; length_refreshed--)
        {
            CRC = (byte)(((int)CRC) ^ (int)Array[length_buffer - length_refreshed]);
        }

        return CRC;
    }
```

**EDIT**
Check here for CRC: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check

Comment: Your "CRC" function looks bogus.  Looks like it simply generates a checksum by exclusive ORing the bytes of the array.